# Gluing PVC junction box for custom size

Tags: electrical

I have a wall that's 2" deep. I'm using 4" square boxes for the outlets, as normal x-gang boxes are too deep. I'm need a 4-gang switch bank in one place. Would it be acceptable/wise to cut the ends off of 2 4" boxes, then glue them together (likely with a couple extra scraps on the top/bottom to strengthen it? Alternatively, could I cut a 4 gang box to the right depth and glue on some cover plats to form the back of it?

And if that's absolutely not an option for some reason, anyone have a source for 4-gang boxes that are 2" deep? I've found 1-gang boxes at Allied Moulded, but their larger boxes are still too deep.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use metal boxes?   They have the kind of metal boxes that come apart and allow you to create X-gang boxes, and I don't _think_ they are over 2" deep.

Comment: Metal boxes are definitely an option. I haven't seen these before - do you happen to know if Home Depot has them (or might you have a link)?

Comment: dont cut the metal boxes that voids the "listing" do what jphil suggest below, they do have some that are shallower but you only have the space for the wire coming in and a device no room for a wire nut , when I use these I usually have to put "splice boxes" in the attic . you cannot put a splice box inside the wall and meet code requirements. the ones I use are "Gangable old work box"

Comment: Do not modify electrical boxes.  Not only are you voiding the listing, you're also changing the volume.  Reducing the volume can lead to increased heat retention within the box, which can lead to damage to components and or fire.

Comment: Why would you want to use a PVC box in an interior wall in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use metal boxes, there is an option that is *exactly* 2" deep.

They went and verbed the word gang, so you're search term is "Gangable Metal Box".  They are sold at most electrical supply places including many Home Depot stores.  They have various models with different types of wings for mounting.

At the bottom of the box in the picture, you can see a small screw.  Removing the screw allows you to take of the side wall and link it up to another box.  You could make a 12-gang box if you wanted to...

[Gangable Box](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Steel-City-1-Gang-Steel-Old-Work-Gangable-Box-16-Pack-CDOWTG-16R/202596375)

[image]

Because it's a metal box, pay attention to grounding.  I believe the box must be grounded, so use grounding screws (there's a hole in the back for one) or ground your switch/outlet and use the type that have the self-grounding straps to ground the box.

Comment: Yep, gangable is the word I wasn't searching for. This should do the trick. Thanks!